# Represent a key value as an enum

Tags: c++

I am reading a value from a config file:

```
txtype=value
```

value can be one of four values: transmit, receiver, transceiver, any. There is lots of existing code for reading the key value pairs from the file so I just have to represent it as a type.

I wanted to represent this as an enum:

```
 enum txtype { transmit = "transmit", receiver = "receiver", transceiver = "transceiver", any = "any" }
```

but I realise now that I can't do that with c++ 98. Are there alternative ways of doing this in c++ 98?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you want. Are you looking for `std::unordered_map`?

Comment: Do you want to get the string values from enum values or you want to get the enum values from string values? Some more code on what you tried, especially some logic, would help people understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will really depend on what your compiler will support. If your compiler supports `map`, then you can simply create a `map` between you string and the integer index which you can assign as the `enum` value using `std::map<std::string, int>`. The `enum` is omitted below since you can define and declare an instance to assign the index returned as you like. A short example using `map` could be, e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main (void) {

    std::map<std::string, int> m = {
        {"transmit", 0},
        {"receiver", 1},
        {"transceiver", 2},
        {"any", 3}
    };
    std::string s;

    while ((std::cin >> s))
        std::cout << s << " - " << m[s] << '\n';
}
```

(**note:** if you are using Visual C++ 12 or earlier, you cannot use the `{...}` universal initializer)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ printf "receiver\ntransceiver\nany\ntransmit\n" | ./bin/map_str_int
receiver - 1
transceiver - 2
any - 3
transmit - 0
```

If your compiler does not support `map`, you can do the same thing using `std::string` and a simple function to compare with the contents of an array of `std::string` returning the index of the matching type, e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

const std::string txstr[] = { "transmit",
                            "receiver",
                            "transceiver",
                            "any" };

const int ntypes = sizeof txstr / sizeof *txstr;

int gettxtype (const std::string& s)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < ntypes; i++)
        if (txstr[i] == s)
            return i;

    return -1;
}

int main (void) {

    std::string s;

    while ((std::cin >> s)) {
        int type =  gettxtype(s);
        if (type >= 0)
            std::cout << s << " - " << type << '\n';
    }
}
```

(as a benefit above, you can determine if the type provided does not match any of the known txtypes by returning `-1` if the matching type is not found.)

The Use/Output is the same. Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is possible with enum .But Hashtable will help you.

Hashtable has key value pair.

Assigning value:

A[transmit]="transmit"  ...

Accesing :

string x;

x=A[transmit] will return transmit.

Here A is your Hashtable  name.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash

Comment: `unordered_map` was introduced in C++1x.  OP is asking specifically for C++98 (well, there are other hashtable implementation available during that time though)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can fake it in some way: Just take advantage of the fact that enumerations in C/C++ are really just numbers, so use your default numbering (as you already have it).
When you read the value as string, search in a `std::array` or a `std::map` for the according mapping and use the index.

In pseudocode:

```
valueAsString <- readStringFromFile;  // your logic
idx <- getIndexFromMap[valueAsString];
yourEnum = static_cast<txtype>(idx);
```

Edit:

Of course a direct mapping from the string representations to the enumeration values would be prefereable here:

```
std::map<std::string, txtype> mapping = { /* initialize */ };

for (auto&& key : keys) {
  process(mapping[key]);
}
```

Comment: iirc, developer is free to assign the ordinal value for each enum value.  Instead of getting the "index", why don't just create a `map` which maps between the string vs enum value directly?

Comment: Well yeah, that's the same procedure shortened down. This is just an alternative, but you're right, I'll adapt my answer.

Comment: it is not only shortening.  Just think how your original code could adapt to things like `enum Foo = {FOO=1, BAR = 5, QUX = 100}`

Comment: We also need to know the compiler the other person is using. C++98 is somewhat ambiguous, especially if it is VS. VS12 and earlier didn't support uniform initialization of containers through `_MSC_VER == 1700`. You still have `map` but not `{ /* initialize */ }`.